# List Slicing in Power Query M Code running into runtime errors with functions being assigned to lists?

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

I am trying to use the following M code in my custom function to slice a list by a list of split offsets.

I am not sure why this line brings up an error. I have localized it using query designer to the last expression before "in."

```
    let
    BodyText = Table1_2,
        splitfunc = SMTSplit,
        SplitLines = Text.Split(BodyText, "#(lf)"),

        CleanedLines = List.Transform(SplitLines, each Text.Remove(_, {":",";"," "})),
        
        SplitCriteria = List.Transform(CleanedLines, each splitfunc(_)),
        
        CriteriaIndexes = List.PositionOf(SplitCriteria, true,Occurrence.All),

        Rejoin = (LineList as list) as text => List.Combine(List.Transform(LineList, each _ + "#(lf)")),
        
        IndexIndex = List.Positions(CriteriaIndexes),
        
        MaxIndexIndex = List.Max(IndexIndex),
        MaxLineIndex = List.Max(List.Positions(SplitLines)),
        BodySplits = List.Transform( IndexIndex, each if _ < MaxIndexIndex
            then List.Range(CriteriaIndexes(_), CriteriaIndexes(_)- CriteriaIndexes(_))
            else List.Range(CriteriaIndexes(_), MaxLineIndex - CriteriaIndexes(_))
        )
in
    BodySplits
```

This results in an expression error indicating that I tried to convert a list to a function.

```
Expression.Error: We cannot convert a value of type List to type Function.
Details:
    Value=[List]
    Type=[Type]
```

If anyone knows of a better way to slice lists by index in Power Query, please let me know!

Edit:
The data in Table1_2 is a string with line returns in it.

```
SMT6
Sometexthere
TMs
Header1

kkagorqr
an

fgaklgas55SMT3
dall

WorkingonSMT6
```

Also, the custom function SMTSplit is:

```
SMTSplit = (TestText as text) => let
    split = Text.Length(TestText) < 6 and Text.Contains(TestText, "SMT")
    in
        split

enter code here
```

Comment: The problem depends on the contents of the unknown Table1_2, so we would need a crystal ball to understand the question.

Comment: I suggest you **edit your question** after reading the HELP topic for this forum on [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using () function syntax where I should have been using {} syntax to access a list element by index.

It works now!

```
= (BodyText as text, splitfunc as function) => let

 SplitLines = Text.Split(BodyText, "#(lf)"),
    CleanedLines = List.Transform(SplitLines, each Text.Remove(_, {":",";"," "})),
    
    SplitCriteria = List.Transform(CleanedLines, each splitfunc(_)),
    
    CriteriaIndexes = List.PositionOf(SplitCriteria, true,Occurrence.All),

    Rejoin = (LineList as list) as text => Text.Combine(List.Transform(LineList, each Text.Combine({_, "#(lf)"}))),
    
    IndexIndex = List.Positions(CriteriaIndexes),
    
    MaxLineIndex = List.Max(List.Positions(SplitLines)),
    BodySplits = List.Transform(IndexIndex, each if _ < List.Max(IndexIndex) and List.Max(IndexIndex) >0
        then Rejoin(List.Range(SplitLines,CriteriaIndexes{_}, CriteriaIndexes{_+1} - CriteriaIndexes{_}))
        else Rejoin(List.Range(SplitLines, CriteriaIndexes{_}, List.Max(List.Positions(SplitLines))))
    ),
LineList = List.Transform(IndexIndex, each CleanedLines{CriteriaIndexes{_}}),
ResultTable = Table.FromColumns({LineList, BodySplits}, {"Line","SplitBody"})
in ResultTable
```